# Bitcoin-related bounties

Tags: services, websites, mining-reward

What is the most common way for one to announce new Bitcoin-related bounties in the community? Is there some website that mediates in the process, or is everything done through the Bitcoin forum?

Comment: For edification, I think bounties are listed here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Active_Bounties but this isn't an "announcement" per se

Comment: A large bounty (e.g., like something a freelancer would take up) or trivial amount, or perhaps a small amount for a specific task?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some bounty sites pop up every now and then. Can't remember any of them. This fact alone suggests that you would not get anywhere the same kind as exposure as on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our service at [bitquestion.com](http://www.bitquestion.com) to post bounties related to questions.

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting, guess I'll have to check it out every now and then.

Comment: Welcome Wladston! You can improve the answer by adding a few more lines describing exactly what Bitquestion is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Booster.io](https://booster.io/) (from the same guy as [Propster.me](https://propster.me/)). It's rather new, so use at your own peril. Of course you should also advertise the bounty at the official forum and other channels.